# How to generate a spring along a circular path?

Tags: inkscape, vector

This picture shows a spring but along a circle.

[image: curved spring]

How can I draw this in Inkscape? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw it horizontal first, group everything, and apply a Bend Live Path Effect, and edit the spine of the Bend

An example

[image]